# Does AsynckTask.onPostExecute and FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments run on same thread (ui thread)?

Tags: android, multithreading, arraylist, android-asynctask, ui-thread

I get  `ConcurrentModificationException` when I traverse the `ArrayList`.
What I did:

```
1.  activity has a ArrayList<Callable>
2.  add Callable to ArrayList when AsyncTask.onPostExecute
3.  traverse the ArrayList to call the callable in onResumeFragments
```

How the exception be triggered:
I make the `AsyncTask.execute()` and press home button quickly, when my app come back to foreground, the exception happened.

What confuses me is:
if  `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` and `FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments` run on same thread,
there won't be a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, right?

> As I know `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` runs on ui thread, and `FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments` should runs on ui thread too,
>   so how `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` happend?

This is my exception stack

```
com.yumei.sdkdemo I/PayMethodActivity: 
  11-10 11:34:35.218 10030-10030/com.yumei.sdkdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yumei.sdkdemo, PID: 10030
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.yumei.sdkdemo/com.yumei.sdk.PayMethodActivity}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2954)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:906)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:701)
 Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
 at com.yumei.sdk.PayMethodFragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(PayMethodActivity.java:116)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:451)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6040)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:906) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:701)
```

thanks for your response.

Comment: `onPostExecute` runs on the thread from which you call the `asyncTask.execute()` method from

Comment: Can you post some code samples as no one can help you by only reading the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you want to delete some items while traverse, you should you Iterator. And if your AsynTask was not created on UI thread, make sure you use thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AsyncTask's onPostexcute is run in UI thread, and I dont think it's thread problem. `ConcurrentModificationException` maybe occurs when you try to `modify` your `Arraylist` while looping its elements (such as remove `Callable` in side `for` loop). 

p/s: you should post your `onPostExcute` code with your logcat.